# compiling znorts blockparser on mavericks - make error

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, clang, osx-mavericks

I wanted to use the infamous "znort" blockparser on my mavericks machine, but am so far unable to compile it.
I'm stuck at the make step.
If I leave the makefile untouched, I get the following error:

```
c++ -- cb/allBalances.cpp
c++ -- callback.cpp
c++ -- cb/closure.cpp
c++ -- cb/dumpTX.cpp
c++ -- cb/help.cpp
c++ -- opcodes.cpp
c++ -- option.cpp
c++ -- parser.cpp
clangclangclang: : : clang: clang: clang: clang: clang: error: error: error: error: error:       error: error: error: unknown argument: '-fno-check-new' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-    error-in-future]unknown argument: '-fno-check-new' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]unknown argument: '-fno-check-new' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]unknown argument: '-fno-check-new' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]unknown argument: '-fno-check-new' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]unknown argument: '-fno-check-new' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]unknown argument: '-fno-check-new' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]unknown argument: '-fno-check-new' [-Wunused-command-line-argument-hard-error-in-future]

clangclang: : notenote: : this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the futurethis will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future


clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future

clang: note: this will be a hard error (cannot be downgraded to a warning) in the future
make: *** [.objs/parser.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
make: *** [.objs/allBalances.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/option.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/opcodes.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/dumpTX.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/closure.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/callback.o] Error 1
make: *** [.objs/help.o] Error 1
```

When I change CPLUS to gcc (instead of g++) and comment out the COPT line, i'm getting a compilation error file "google/dense-hash-maps not found".

…and you may have guessed it, i'm unable to compile them too…

I am now biting my tongue for two days, so any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I saw this issue on GitHub which suggests you run `sudo apt-get install sparsehash` to resolve the error. Haven't tried it but I hope it helps.

https://github.com/znort987/blockparser/issues/2

Comment: Hi Anwell, thanks for your suggestion! I did indeed miss to install sparsehash. …but also a few other minor glitches. Anyway, was finally successful, after lots of trouble at link time.